# Reverse geocoder not working properly when used in a loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

My problem is with reverse geocoding using Google Maps. I would like to geocode n number(less than 15) of latitude and longitude coordinates so that I can plot a route using the addresses obtained. My problem is when I am using it in a loop it is not giving addresses in the order of lat-lng coordinates passed. The loop is not executing properly. The part of the code that I am having trouble with is:

```
 for(var i=0;i<tlength;i++){
 alert(i);    
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();   
 geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng[i]},function(results, status) {
 alert(i); 
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        var add=results[0].formatted_address;
        address.push(add);
      }
    }
  });    
 }
```

The address array obtained is not in order with the latlng array. Second latlng is getting geocoded first and also the value of i from the 2nd alert box is always 6(in this case tlength=6). It should change from 0 to 5. But it's not happening. Can someone help me with this. Or is their any other way to plot routes using latlong coorinates directly?

Comment: Geocoding is asynchronous.  The ordering of the callbacks is not guaranteed in in time.  One fix would be to use function closure to associate the input index to the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Geocoding is asynchronous.  The ordering of the callbacks is not guaranteed in in time.  One fix would be to use function closure to associate the input index to the callback.  Note that the geocoder is subject to a quota and a rate limit.  If you don't check for the status returned you won't know when you run into the limit. (the alerts in the code below will get really annoying if you have lots of points in your array...)

```
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();   
 function reverseGeocode(index) {
   geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng[index]},function(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       if (results[0]) {
         var add=results[0].formatted_address;
         address[index] = add;
       } else alert("no results for "+laglng[index]);
     } else alert("Geocode failed: "+status);
   });    
 }

 for(var i=0;i<tlength;i++){
   reversGeocode(i);
 }
```

Comment: Even I have included the alert box in the beginning. Since I am testing for some random values, have removed that part. Can you please help me with the function closure you have just mentioned. Any link with information regarding function closure will help me a lot.Thank you for the reply.

Comment: The "reverseGeocode" function in my answer gets function closure on the "index" variable.  One reference would be [Mike Williams' explanation from his v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/closure.htm).

Comment: Thanks. That helped me a lot. Now my address is updating properly. But I am getting an alert "Geocode failed: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" if I increase number of points. Is there any other way to make reverse geocoing work even if I increase number of points?

Comment: That (running into the query limit) is the problem with reverse geocoding (or geocoding) lots of points.  The best solution is to either store the address in a database with the coordinates (so you don't need to use Google's resources to get it back) or if you only ever had the coordinates, do the reverse geocoding "offline" and "cache" the results in a database (refreshing them periodically to comply with the terms of service), or build your own reverse geocoder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like this error in your code :

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.9000,8.4731);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();   
     geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng},function(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (results[0]) {
            var add=results[0].formatted_address;
            //address.push(add);
             alert(results[0].formatted_address); 
          }
        }
      });
```

And for your code you need to pass like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<tlength;i++){ 
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlng[i]);
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();   
 geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng},function(results, status) {
 alert(i); 
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
       // var add=results[0].formatted_address;
        address.push(results[0].formatted_address);
      }
    }
  });    
 }
```

Comment: sorry I hadn't uploaded my entire code here. I have used 'var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.9000,8.4731);' in the previous line which I haven't uploaded here. Is there any other way? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: no it is easiest way i don't know if any. I always use this one in my many application